# Removing elements from Array of double

Tags: java

How to remove all the occurences of element from array of doubles. Consider

```
double[] arr = { 0.0,4.8,5.1,0.0,9.8}
```

I want the output as `{4.8,5.1,9.8}`

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#without

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate through array elements and if it's not equals zero, you remember it, and increment counter. after cycle you would get something like

{4.8, 5.1, 9.8, 0.0, 9.8}
current = 3.

and then you use arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, current); to remove unused values
and get result in fresh array {4.8, 5.1, 9.8}

```
    double[] arr = {0.0, 4.8, 5.1, 0.0, 9.8};
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            arr[current++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, current);
```

Answer (score 1):

With power of java 8 streams you can do it easy!

```
double[] arr = {0.0, 4.8, 5.1, 0.0, 9.8};

double[] result = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .filter(e -> e != 0.0)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new array so

```
List<Double> removals = Arrays.asList(arr);
while(removals.remove(0.00)) {}
double [] newArr = removals.toArray(new String[removals.size()]);
arr = newArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double[] numbers = {0.0,4.8,5.1,0.0,9.8};
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(Double.valueOf(0)));
    numbers = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```